# How to reencode stream in fly and translate?

Tags: streaming, icecast

I have urls to the Icecast/Shoutcast streams, how can i relay these streams in multiple bitrates? I know how to reencode file, but don't know how to reencode stream in multiple bitrates.

```
For example i find two icecast/shoutcast stream url/server:

http://icecast_stream.ru:8000/play
http://shoutcast_stream:8000/

I want to relay it in multiple bitrates:
http://localhost:8000/icecast_stream_32
http://localhost:8000/icecast_stream_64
http://localhost:8000/icecast_stream_128


http://localhost:8000/shoutcast_stream_32
http://localhost:8000/shoutcast_stream_64
http://localhost:8000/shoutcast_stream_128
```

Can I do it with Icecast + Ices or which soft i need to use?

Comment: Dupe and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31457695/2648865